# How to add an SSH key to a local CircleCI build?

Tags: ssh, circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm trying to run a CircleCI test job locally by running

```
circleci local execute --job test
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

```
go: github.com/some/repo@v0.0.0-20180921204022-800easdf7ec: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/52f8e69c46f5a1cc77e6bf: exit status 128:
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I would basically like to do the equivalent of https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/add-ssh-key/ for the local CircleCI environment, but there is no way to go to Project Settings -> Checkout SSH Keys as described in that documentation. I've read the documentation at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/#run-a-job-in-a-container-on-your-machine but wasn't able to find a way to do this.

Any idea how I can check out code from private Github repos in the local CircleCI environment?

Comment: What do you mean by: _"there is no way to go to Project Settings -> Checkout SSH Keys as described in that documentation"_?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the key to your SSH keychain?

`ssh-add (location of ssh key)`

This should add it to the keychain and CircleCI local should pick it up.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and am able to clone the private repositories when working locally. It seems only not to work in the containerized local CircleCI environment.

Comment: Have you tried the ssh key option?
```--checkout-key=PATH```
Make sure you have the right permissions 644.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--checkout-key` argument

```
circleci local execute build --checkout-key id_rsa
```

*Note: `id_rsa` should be in the same folder*